# How can I access .onion top level domains?

Tags: tor

Using Tor Browser, I cannot access .onion domains. Instead, the browser is waiting for example.onion until the connection times out.

First, download Tor Browser from https://torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en, open it, connect to the Tor network, and enter a .onion address (whichever you can find) in the address bar. Among many others, I found Core.onion: eqt5g4fuenphqinx.onion. That address would yield an attempt to connect and then nothing.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You aren't telling us what you're doing, so how can we guess what you're doing wrong?

Comment: Sure, will give it a try. First, download Tor browser from https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en, open it, connect to the tor network, enter a .onion address in the address bar, whichever you can find. Among many others, I found Core.onion: eqt5g4fuenphqinx.onion. That would yield an attempt to connect and then nothing.

Comment: Please [edit] clarifications into the question itself. Comments can be deleted. (Note that I don't know enough about Tor to answer this myself; I'm just trying to help you to create a better quality question, which is then more likely to attract an answer.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I did nothing wrong, it was just bad links. Found some that worked.
Duckduckgo: http://3g2upl4pq6kufc4m.onion/ 
Facebook: https://facebookcorewwwi.onion/